how to update device twin using python?
I am currently trying to update a property in device twin using python. but unable to do it due to SSL error.
below is the code
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
import certifi
import ssl

# Connect to IoT Hub and send message to device
CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=iothub-jein02-np-eas-ua-eztr01.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=service;SharedAccessKey=Mmjc..."
DEVICE_ID = "NodeMCU"

'''first used this method'''
#ca_cert_path = "D:/new/cacert.pem"

'''later used this method'''
# Set the CA certificates globally
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())

try:
    # Create IoTHubRegistryManager
    registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING, connection_verify = False)
   
    # Update the desired properties
    twin = registry_manager.update_twin(DEVICE_ID, {
        "properties": {
            "desired": {
                "temp": "100"
                }
        }
    })

except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Error sending message to device: {str(ex)}")
    raise

following is the error I'm getting

msrest.exceptions.ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request., SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='iothub-jein02-np-eas-ua-eztr01.azure-devices.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /twins/NodeMCU?api-version=2021-04-12 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

Also, how to do this in 443 port (open port) it tried connection_verify = False.
it says connection_verify command error
how to rectify this errors.

Have you tried using  Custom CA  or if using in a test env then disable SSL Verification but I feel the best approach is to use a custom CA bundle with the certifi library to ensure SSL verification is properly handled.

@sai are you using connection string to connect or certificate to connect to azure IoT Hub.

Im using service connection string.

hi @Arko if I use Custom CA then where I should give the path my path is D:/new/ca_file.perm
if I add ca_cert argument from_connection_string function it says
"TypeError: IoTHubRegistryManager.from_connection_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ca_cert'

The below code is to update the desired properties of an IoT device twin in Azure IoT Hub using the Azure IoT Python SDK
Install the below package using pip,
pip install azure-iot-hub

It updates the desired property of your IoT device twin to set temp to "100"
I used this MSDOC to Understand and use device twins in IoT Hub

import sys
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
from azure.iot.hub.models import Twin, TwinProperties


IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING = "<iot-hub-connection-string>"
DEVICE_ID = "<device-id>"

iothub_registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING)

try:
    
    twin = iothub_registry_manager.get_twin(DEVICE_ID)

 
    desired = {
        "temp": "100"
    }

   
    twin_patch = Twin(properties=TwinProperties(desired=desired))

    
    updated_twin = iothub_registry_manager.update_twin(DEVICE_ID, twin_patch, twin.etag)

    print("Desired property 'temp' set to '100' successfully.")
except Exception as ex:
    print("Unexpected error:", ex)


Output:

Device twin:

Refer to this sample example for using X.509 certificate authentication in python.

Can I use port 443 here because my 8883 port is blocked. If I can where to add the parameter.

Have to tried my code with  connection string with deviceid.

tried your code in my personal pc it is working but the "temp": "100" is placed under "$version": 2 not like yours. but in my organization laptop I'm getting SSL error

Glad to know it working in personal pc .

Use SSL certificate  trust by Azure IoT Hub  from this SO. refer link to ssl in pc

As its working on your personal System then no issue with any Code/Config, the issue with certificate in your Org system can be taken care by your IT admin.
